# GWT: How to extract a content of a javascript function using (JSNI)

Tags: gwt, jsni

I am calling a javascript function from gwt client side using JSNI like follow:

```
anchor.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
               execute(notification.getActionCode(), notification.getParams());
            }
});

private static native String execute(String functionName, String params)/*-{
        try{
           $wnd[functionName](params);
        }catch(e){
            alert(e.message);
        }
}-*/;
```

My problem is that my javascript function contains window.open("ServletName?....").
When clicking on the anchor, the window opened with error below:
**The requested resource (/es/*gwt/core*/ServletName) is not available.**

if i replace window.open("ServletName?....") by window.open("../../ServletName?...."), the window open successfully, but these javascript functions are used also outside gwt so i cant modify it .

I dont know why the part /gwt/core is being added to the url which is causing the problem.
Is there a way in gwt before executing the javascript function, to extract its content and adding the "../.." before the url? ***i mean heaving the javascript function name, can we get its content before calling the execute function? in my case my javascript function is a follow:***

```
function everlinked_AddSpace(spaceId){
        window.open('ELUtilities?Service=Space&action=homePage&SpaceId='+spaceId+'&Template=apps/everlinked/templates/spaces/space_main.htm','_blank');;
    }
```

***i need to modify it in gwt client side and call it with the new modifications.***

I appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: I have updated my post. I hope it is clearer. I dont know if this is the right solution. If you have any better solution i will be grateful.

Comment: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#getHostPageBaseURL()

Comment: Thank you Baadshah for your help. but where i should use the method getHostPageBaseURL()

Comment: My jsni method is the one containing the url to be modified. if i get the base url by GWT.get...URL() how can i include it in my jnsi method?

Comment: Either pass it as an argument of your method, or call it from JS using JSNI syntax: `@com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT::getHostPageBaseURL()`.

Comment: Thank you Andrea, but i'm afraid i cant modify the arguments neither the content of my method defined in JS as it is used in another service outside gwt environment. That's why i was looking if i can get the content of my js method inside gwt, add the getHostPageBaseURL() to the url and call it in the execute function. i am still a beginner in GWT so maybe this can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to resolve your problem using a bad approach.

The easier way is to use an url [re-writer](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/), or to modify your web.xml `url-pattern` to route the relative path sent by your gwt app to the same servlet.

Probably you have in your web.xml something like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>maynamespace.ServletName</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ServletName</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So you can add this block to your web.xml.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/es/gwt/core/ServletName</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Note that `url-pattern` has a very limited set of regular expressions (/path/* and *.ext), so in your case you have to write the full path.